# Weired situation. I'm exactly following install tutorial but failed

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm following ROS fuerte install tutorial (install from source).
By the way, I got following error message.
I just re-installed my Ubuntu 12.04. Very clean. I didn't install anything.

```
hyon@hyon-t61:~$ rosdep install -a
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
depth_image_proc: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
rotate_recovery: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
gazebo_plugins: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
gazebo_worlds: Missing resource protobuf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
hyon@hyon-t61:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
hyon@hyon-t61:~$
```

Why the tutorial does not work? Nobody doing that?

Added:

I also tested following.

```
hyon@hyon-t61:~/Libraries$ rosdep resolve pcl
#apt
ros-fuerte-pcl
```

Does this make sense? Source install requires ros-fuerte-pcl.
I think something wrong...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38995/weired-situation.-i%27m-exactly-following-install-tutorial-but-failed./) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been going through some similar issues trying to install on PandaBoard from source.  The reason someone *will* need to install from source in Precise, is if they are on an ARM processor (i.e. BeagleBoard, PandaBoard, etc.) - no debian packages for ARM (yet*).

As far as my understanding goes:

1. ros-fuerte-pcl is a 3rd party dependency (`<rosdep>` key 'pcl'), which has been patched/wrapped into it's own debian package on Willow's [wg-debs](https://github.com/wg-debs) github (so that it plays nice with ROS).
2. There are a bunch of funky naming things going on with 'pcl'-related packages/stacks/dependencies.

- EX:

  `$ rosdep keys pcl
  pcl
  $ rosdep resolve pcl
  #apt
  ros-fuerte-pcl
  $ rospack find pcl
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/pcl
  $ roslocate info pcl
  - svn: local-name: pcl uri: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl
  $ roslocate type pcl
  package`

  Btw, `http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl`, doesn't exist

  - Some packages depend on a ROS package named 'pcl' (`<depend package="pcl"/>`), and some depend on an external package, with the key 'pcl' (`<rosdep name="pcl"/>` e.g. ros-fuerte-pcl).
  - And, I'm not completely sure, but I believe that the "Missing resource pcl" will be satisfied when you install ros-fuerte-pcl (from package or source). There is a subfolder 'ros' in the ros-fuerte-pcl package whose contents get installed in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/pcl (which is where '`rospack find pcl`' points me in my debian package install of Fuerte on Precise x86 machine).
  - Side note: perception_pcl includes a ROS package 'pcl_ros' which I think used to mostly serve to pull in the external dependency.

3. Also, currently rosdep doesn't work for `<rosdep>` dependencies in stacks (stack.xml). It just ignores them.  Thus, if you have to build stacks from source that list their dependencies at the stack level (e.g. ros-fuerte-pcl, opencv) you have to manually go into the stack.xml and install each (debian) package it lists.  You may need to resolve those `<rosdep>` keys into actual package names using rosdep.
4. You will also notice that you're "missing resource protobuf".  This is from packages in simulator_gazebo depending on a ROS package called protobuf.  The protobuf ROS package/stack exists for Ubuntu Lucid and earlier, which did not distribute the proper version of the library. In Precise, there should be a protobuf debian package (libprotobuf7), even for ARM, which I'd recommend you just apt-get install manually.  Then you can just comment out the shell ROS dependency, `<depend package="protobuf"/>`, from the manifest.xml's in `gazebo_words` and `gazebo`.  Your missing protobuf resource should disappear in a `rosdep check -a`

Sorry if that was a bit of an overload; hopefully it shines some light on what's going on.  Also, related FYI: http://answers.ros.org/question/35602/ros-fuerte-pandaboard-ubuntu-1204-no-go/

*There might be `armel` packages (BeagleBoard) possible in the near future, but `armhf` (PandaBoard) not as much.

---

Originally posted by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) with karma: 271 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-08-24**:
How can I install ros-fuerte-pcl? I can't find it anywhere... Would be great to get a hint

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-10-11**:
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pcl

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-16**:
"Side note: perception_pcl includes a ROS package 'pcl_ros' which I think used to mostly serve to pull in the external dependency." `$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception-pcl` is what fixed "missing ros_pcl" error so if you're getting warnings of missing ros-pcl merely install perception-pcl